# TCP Traceroute in Python- getting stuck

Tags: networking, tcp, traceroute

I am writing a python traceroute that send TCP SYN probes and my script seems tog et stuck on a certain hop every time. How can I use threading to listen for both TCP and ICMP packets and have an output like that of TCP traceroute.

[My program running and getting stuck.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6JXa.png)

[Desired output of TCP traceroute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obdBR.png)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow this tutorial : https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/
so you understand and apply the threading on your python script
moreover it well be great to share the code so i can figure out why it stuck as you said.